# LuaTeX - Just print an argument

Tags: luatex

I would like to parse an argument using a Lua code but the basic code below fails. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function calctree(a)     
  tex.print(">>>"..a.."<<<")
end    
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\calctree[1]{\directlua{calctree(#1)}}%


\begin{document}    

\calctree{OOO}
\calctree{a (b + 3) - c**2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\calctree{"a (b + 3) - c**2"}` works fine.

Comment: Yes but it is more convenient to type directly without the quotes.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from defining the macro `\calctree` as either `\newcommand\calctree[1]{\directlua{calctree("#1")}}` or as `\newcommand\calctree[1]{\directlua{calctree(\luastring{#1})}}`, is there?

Comment: Ok. That is memorized. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX is a macro language, so your code expands to `\directlua{calctree(a (b + 3) - c**2)}`. Now Lua has no reason to treat this argument of a string since there are no quotes, so it is interpreted as a Lua expression instead. Since `a`, `b`, and `c` are undefined and `**` is not a valid Lua operator, this fails.

You can read your argument as a string instead by using `token.scan_argument`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function calctree(a)     
  tex.print(">>>"..a.."<<<")
end    
\end{luacode}

% This fully expands the argument
\newcommand\calctree{\directlua{calctree(token.scan_argument())}}%

% This would suppress the expansion
%\newcommand\calctreE[2]{\directlua{calctree(token.scan_argument())}{\unexpanded{#1}}}%


\begin{document}    

\calctree{OOO}
\calctree{a (b + 3) - c**2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\def\calctree#1{\directlua{calctree("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}` is not sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for `token.scan_argument()`. What is the best reference to learn to interact with TeX from Lua (for Lua alone I have a book somewhere under one of my wardrobes)?

Comment: @wipet `\luaescapestring` works too, but it's longer, you have to remember which quotes to use, it's slower, less compatible if you later want to move the functionality into a \luafunction/\luadef/..., and doesn't separate clearly between Lua and TeX code. But mostly I simply like the `token` functions more.

Comment: +1. Since the OP loads the `luacode` package, you could also that package's `\luastring` and `\luastringN` commands. E.g., `\newcommand\calctree[1]{\directlua{calctree(\luastringN{#1})}}`. (The `N` in `\luastringN` stands for "no expension". Speaking for myself, I find `\luastringN` more mnemonic than `token.scan_argument`.) Also, I'd replace `tex.print(">>>"..a.."<<<")` with `tex.print(">\\kern0pt>\\kern0pt>"..a.."<\\kern0pt<\\kern0pt<")`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for pointing that (I am starting to use LuaTeX...). Your solution should work with several arguments.